# C# common substring list/extraction

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, substring

My goal is to run through a database of strings and get the count each time each substring occurs. In other words I need to extract all possible word combinations from the string.

For example the input might be `"this is the first string"`.

I would want to extract `"this is"`, `"is the"`, `"the first"`, `"first string"`, `"this is the"`, `"is the first"`, `"the first string"`, `"this is the first"`, `"is the first string"`.

I only need to go left to right, always in order.

I am not really sure where to start with this. I already have the code to read database and save into list, just need to know how to extract all possible sub strings based on the space character.

Comment: On the premise that any substring of three words or more must contain substrings of two words, you need only actually search for substrings containing two words.

Comment: shure the combination "this is the first string" is not an allowed combination? ... anyway, this looks like a recursion algorithm

Comment: Having just answered a similar question, but where only phrases of _exactly_ `n` words were required, with a regular expression, I'd be curious as to whether there's a regular expression that will solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method builds up a list of the indices of all spaces in your string (plus notional start and end spaces), then returns the substring between every ordered pair of indices:

```
static IEnumerable<string> SpaceDelimitedSubstrings(string input)
{
    List<int> indices = new List<int> { -1 };
    int current = -1;
    while ((current = input.IndexOf(' ', current + 1)) > -1)
    {
        indices.Add(current);
    }
    indices.Add(input.Length);

    int minLength = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < indices.Count - minLength; i++)
        for (int j = i + minLength; j < indices.Count; j++)
            yield return input.Substring(indices[i] + 1, indices[j] - indices[i] - 1);
}
```

Called as follows

```
string input = "this is the first string";
foreach (var s in SpaceDelimitedSubstrings(input))
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

it gives

[image: this]

Changing `minLength` to `2` will cut out the single-word returns.

Answer (score 2):

```
    List<string> WordCombinations(string phrase)
    {
        List<string> combinations = new List<string>();

        string[] words = phrase.Split();

        // We want all 2 word combinations, then 3, then 4, ...
        for (int take = 2; take < words.Length; take++)
        {
            // Start with the first word, then second, then ...
            for (int skip = 0; skip + take <= words.Length; skip++)
            {
                combinations.Add(string.Join(" ", words.Skip(skip).Take(take).ToArray()));
            }
        }

        return combinations;
    }
```

Comment: @Beachwalker: There is a `string.Join` method that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx; the original code was valid.

Comment: @MichaeEdenfield Ah, tried with 3.5 framework. The overload with IEnumerable<T> is available with 4.0 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [String.Split()?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Then you have all single words and only need the possible combinations in addition.

A simple sample to do the thing mentioned above:

```
        string input = "this is the first string";

        var items = input.Split(' ');
        var result = new List<string>();

        // this gets only 2-word-combinations
        for (var i = 0; i < items.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            result.Add(items[i] + " " + items[i + 1]);
        }

        // from this point: search the 3-words etc. or put this in recursion
```

Answer (score 0):

One way might be:

```
myString.Split()
```

If you do not provide any arguments, it will split the string ignoring space characters (tabs, newline (s.a. Environment.NewLine), etc.).

When you have all substrings, you could easily linq your way through them.
Bear in mind this might be slow, because you will have to go through the string each time to extract the substrings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.Split()` in order to parse a string into tokens. Then, you could combine those tokens in order to create the combinations you want.